# Value_counts() for each of the columns in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose I have a dataset like this:

| ID | Department | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HR | senior |
| 2 | IT | junior |
| 3 | IT | middle |
| 4 | IT | middle |
| 5 | IT | senior |
| 6 | HR | middle |
| 7 | Design | middle |
| 8 | Design | middle |

How do i transform this dataset using value_counts() towards every column, so that end result looks like this:

| Department | Department_Count | Level | Level_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 2 | middle | 1 |
|  |  | senior | 1 |
| IT | 4 | junior | 1 |
|  |  | middle | 2 |
|  |  | senior | 1 |
| Design | 2 | middle | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating 2 groupby dataframes, one for each of the counts, and merging them together.

Department counts:

```
dept = df.groupby('Department', as_index=False).count()[['Department', 'ID']]
dept = dept.rename(columns = {'ID':'Department_Count'})

  Department  ID
0     Design   2
1         HR   2
2         IT   4
```

Level counts:

```
level = df.groupby(['Department', 'Level'], as_index=False).count()
level = level.rename(columns = {'ID':'Level_Count'})

  Department   Level  Level_Count
0     Design  middle            2
1         HR  middle            1
2         HR  senior            1
3         IT  junior            1
4         IT  middle            2
5         IT  senior            1
```

Then merge the two together on Department

```
df_out = dept.merge(level, on='Department')

  Department  ID   Level  Level_Count
0     Design   2  middle            2
1         HR   2  middle            1
2         HR   2  senior            1
3         IT   4  junior            1
4         IT   4  middle            2
5         IT   4  senior            1
```

To get the Nans in the Department and ID columns as requested, you could use .loc to find the duplicated rows in those columns, and replace with Nan (will need to `import numpy as np`):

```
df_out.loc[df_out[['Department', 'ID']].duplicated(), ['Department', 'ID']] = np.nan

  Department   ID   Level  Level_Count
0     Design  2.0  middle            2
1         HR  2.0  middle            1
2        NaN  NaN  senior            1
3         IT  4.0  junior            1
4        NaN  NaN  middle            2
5        NaN  NaN  senior            1
```

Comment: The thing is: in Department column 2,4,5 rows are supposed to be np.NaN - i can't replace them manually because actual dataset contains 300k+ rows

Comment: @DilraboKodirova have edited, does mean you no longer know which department the levels are associated with for those rows